# Redmi 3 stuck on bootloop with no recovery mode access

Tags: boot, hardware, adb, recovery-mode

I have a Redmi 3 MIUI7 that I recently flashed with MIUI9 using TWRP. Right after flashing, I tried to boot it but it stuck on a bootloop. Since I haven't booted into the ROM and can't do so because of the bootloop, I have no access to enable USB Debugging AND TWRP recovery mode. No USB Debugging means the device will show as `unauthorized` when using `adb devices`, though I can Vol. Down+Power to get into Fastboot. I have flashed several ROMs before flashing to MIUI9 (Resurrect Remix and LineageOS, both Android Oreo and had root access).

I just need way to boot into TWRP recovery mode to a) flash my way out of the loop b) restore a backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access only to fastboot you will need complete ROM (including BOOTLOADER and FULL SYSTEM) because ota upgrade can broke custom bootloader

Comment: I can't use adb/fastboot commands because the device is "unauthorized"

Comment: Congratulation to new BRICK. Since you don't have any access to the device. The manufacturer may be able to reflash it on the board level.

Comment: You can use fastboot commands in fastboot mode. Fastboot has no relation to the USB debugging setting which is only for the ADB.

Comment: @singhnsk Fastboot can be disabled on some phones from os. Then they can reject commands.

Comment: @Aroly7 that's interesting. I haven't encountered such a setting on MiUi though. Is it the case, @dsw?

Comment: @dsw can you run `fastboot oem device-info` in fastboot?

Comment: @Aroly7 yes, tampered: false, unlocked: false, charger screen enabled:false

Comment: @singhnsk As I said. With bricked fastboot, He cants do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I can not answer in comments nor edit previous answer, so i have to post here. If you already [downloaded](https://www.xiaomigeek.com/edl-mode-xiaomi.html) `AdbWinApi.dll` `AdbWinUsbApi.dll` `fastboot_edl.exe` and started EDL Mode with `edl.cmd` with no result, then try this

1) Turn off your phone.
2) Now plug one end of the USB Cable into the PC port and the other end does not connect to the phone.
3)  Press the `Volume Up` and `Power` buttons and immediately connect the other end of USB Cable to the phone.
4) Automatically the phone will go to EDL Mode with LED lights will light up blinking.

If this not working you should watch a tutorial how to build Deep Flash Cable or how to open the case and boot into EDL from test point.

Comment: source: https://www.smartphones.how/repair/edl-mode